# Need to do 2 group in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, drilldown

Hello i need to do a report in crystal report with 2 group, first groug: hourbyproject and the second: expence. i need them separeted and i need too have a detail for each one when i double clic for the drilldown

exemple :

Group 1 Project :

```
 -project 1
 -project 2
 -project 3
```

Group 2 expence

```
 -expence 1
 -expence 2
```

note each project are in a datatable and each expence are in a other datatable and i need that when i drill down i show only the chosen item

ty for you help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should create a view that truncates both tables (assuming you are using an SQL based data source), it will need to be something like:

```
CREATE VIEW MYVIEWNAME

AS 

SELECT 'Project' AS [TypeName],
       Somefield,
       SomeOtherField

FROM MyProjectTable

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Expense' AS [TypeName],
       Somefield,
       SomeOtherField

FROM MyExpenseTable
```

Then once you add this as a source in Crystal you can group by `TypeName` first then group by the project/Expense.

If you want different details displayed, create a new details section and add the suppression formula `{Mytable.TypeName}="Project"` to the Expense section and vise versa for the Project section.